# How can passive terms be rendered in the calculation of an MFA in R?

Tags: r, data-analysis, missing-data, factorial, factominer

I want to create an MFA using the dedicated function in the FactoMineR package. However, certain variable modalities tend to strongly influence the final structure of the space. I would therefore like to make these modalities passive in this factor space calculation. I have the impression that, as with the MCAs, the excl parameter can be used to do this by specifying the terms to be excluded for each group of variables.

Unfortunately, I don't understand how this parameter should be set. Does anyone know how to set this parameter?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. If you want general statistical/modeling advice, you should ask for help at [stats.se] instead.